# What do I need to know to write a program that change audio output of another process?

Tags: c#, winapi, audio

For some time I was looking at possibility to change CS:GO default audio output device. I found programs like Indievolume or Chevolume. Where you can change for a application audio output. These programs are not free, and I need it only for CS:GO.

I have some experience in c# and I assume I have to get process of this application but I don't know what to do later, and how to get list of audio outputs.

Comment: Seems interesting. I'd love to see an answer to this

Comment: If I will know how to get application audio output, I will write it for free.

Comment: I will take a guess (thus in comments and not an answer) that the way you could influence another process is if you switch default device. The process is supposed to react to the message/notification from the OS and re-route the audio to the new "default" device. You can take a look at `Core Audio APIs that started with Vista, I think.

Comment: G. Stoynev, thanks I will look into that API